# StringBuilder to file maintaining format

Tags: c#, file, format, stringbuilder

in c#, how can i do to export to file a stringbuilder that has multiple lines, mantaining the lines. here's my code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(consulta, SqlConn))
{
  using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (reader != null && reader.Read())
    {
      builder.AppendFormat("{0,-5}  {1,-10}  {2,-10} {3,-18} {4,-10}  {5,-2}  {6,-10} {7,-5} {8,-10}", Convert.ToString(reader[0]), reader.GetDateTime(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), reader.GetDateTime(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), Convert.ToString(reader[3]), Convert.ToString(reader[4]), "06", Convert.ToString(reader[5]), Convert.ToString(reader[6]), Convert.ToString(reader[7]));
    }
  }
}
```

and here's where i save the file, but it's not respecting the lines.

```
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, builder.ToString());
```

Comment: builder.AppendFormat does not break the lines ?

Comment: When you debug, break before the `writealltext`. What does the text view show? That may be your problem. You can simply add a `\n` to the end of your string format if that is the issue.

Comment: @thantos agree. Another option - make `builder.AppendLine();` call

Comment: i resolved it with AppendLine(string.Format(...)). i was not breaking the lines. sorry

Comment: Why not write straight to the `FileStream`, whats the point of an intermediate `StringBuilder`? It incurrs the cost of memory allocation for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `AppendLine` method to insert a line break:

```
builder.AppendFormat(...);
builder.AppendLine();
builder.AppendFormat(...);
```

where ever you need a line break.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Environment.NewLine to add new line to the end of each line in builder.

```
builder.AppendFormat("{0,-5}  {1,-10}  {2,-10} {3,-18} {4,-10}  {5,-2}  {6,-10} {7,-5} {8,-10}{9}", Convert.ToString(reader[0]), reader.GetDateTime(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), reader.GetDateTime(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), Convert.ToString(reader[3]), Convert.ToString(reader[4]), "06", Convert.ToString(reader[5]), Convert.ToString(reader[6]), Convert.ToString(reader[7]), Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't if more efficient and simpler to do this, this avoids the unnecessary use of `StringBuilder` and the overhead of allocating memory for the intermediate `String`.

I've also added the extra `AppendLine` to delimit your rows with new lines.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(consulta, SqlConn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader != null && reader.Read())
            {
                writer.AppendFormat(
"{0,-5}  {1,-10}  {2,-10} {3,-18} {4,-10}  {5,-2}  {6,-10} {7,-5} {8,-10}", 
                    Convert.ToString(reader[0]),
                    reader.GetDateTime(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                    reader.GetDateTime(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                    Convert.ToString(reader[3]),
                    Convert.ToString(reader[4]), 
                    "06",
                    Convert.ToString(reader[5]),
                    Convert.ToString(reader[6]),
                    Convert.ToString(reader[7]));
                writer.AppendLine();
           }
       }
    }
}
```

I also suggest that you could improve the readability of you code like this, although this could be considered subjective,

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(consulta, SqlConn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader != null && reader.Read())
            {
                writer.AppendFormat("{0, -7}", reader[0]);
                writer.AppendFormat("{0:yyyy-MM-dd, -12}", reader.GetDateTime(1));
                writer.AppendFormat("{0:yyyy-MM-dd, -11}", reader.GetDateTime(2));
                writer.AppendFormat("{0, -19}", reader.[3]);
                writer.AppendFormat("{0, -12}06", reader.[4]);
                writer.AppendFormat("{0, -11}, reader.[5]);
                writer.AppendFormat("{0, -6}, reader.[6]);
                writer.AppendFormat("{0, -10}, reader.[7]);
                writer.AppendLine();
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And where are you see new lines in your string builder? Try this:

```
while (reader != null && reader.Read())
{
     builder.AppendFormat("{0,-5}  {1,-10}  {2,-10} {3,-18} {4,-10}  {5,-2}  {6,-10} {7,-5} {8,-10}{9}", Convert.ToString(reader[0]), reader.GetDateTime(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), reader.GetDateTime(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), Convert.ToString(reader[3]), Convert.ToString(reader[4]), "06", Convert.ToString(reader[5]), Convert.ToString(reader[6]), Convert.ToString(reader[7]), Environment.NewLine);
}
```